# Merge org-mode files wirth emerge

Tags: org-mode, emerge

I am using the excellent emerge-files command to merge two files regularly to handle conflict when syncing two computers. However when used on org-mode files, in the split-windows at the top that display my two files to be merged, the headings are folded (as per my config) and I can't unfold them due to the buffers being read-only.

I have two questions: can I manually unfold the org-mode files? and second, can this be done automatically through some emerge hook or something?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't try with `emerge` but if I have a RO buffer of an ORG file and I do `S-TAB` on it, it cycles through the folding states: I don't have to make the buffer RW.

Comment: It works, thanks!